# Onclick Event Sometimes Doesn't Fire (IE6/IE7/IE8)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onclick

I noticed that sometimes IE6/IE7/IE8 don't always fire onclick events (from buttons when clicked). 
There seems to be a grace period of a couple of a seconds after the last onclick event has been fired.

I decided to test this behaviour using this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function(){
                    document.getElementById('clicker').onclick = function(){
                        var i = 0
                        return function(){
                            i+= 1
                            this.value = i.toString()
                        }
                    }()
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <input type="submit" value="click here" id="clicker"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Browser Comparison (at 1/4 speed)](http://imgur.com/BDSu2Qy)
As you might be able to see, it takes around two clicks of the button to get the event to fire on IE 6-8, whilst for 9/firefox/chrome the event is fire every time.

What could be the cause for this? The IE6 and 8 were tested on a virtual machine (VirtualBox) with Windows XP.

Other:

- I had the same results with both 'submit' and 'button'.
- Using 'Onmouseup' as an alternative to onclick seems to work.

Comment: I dont know why, but maybe your doctype could be an issue? Try using the HTML5 doctype: <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: IE 6 to 8 doesn't implement the HTML5 API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In olders versions of IE you have to handle both Click and Double-click.

If you don't do that, only the first click of your double-click will be treated, giving you this illusion.

Try this :

```
window.onload = function() {
    var i = 0;
    document.getElementById('clicker')
        .onclick = function() { this.value = (i+=1).toString() };
    document.getElementById('clicker')
        .ondblclick = function() { this.value = (i+=1).toString() };
}
```

Comment: Thank you that solved it for me. Onmouseup seems to work too for some reason.